# C: Problem with Reading a .txt file into a 2D array

Tags: c, image

I am trying to read an Ascii-image given as a txt-file, called "ascii_image.txt", into a 2D character array. I am using function called "getAsciiImageDimension" to obtain the "dimensions" of the file and then store the image in a 2D char array, "array", of the dimension found before. Both function follow a character by character approach.

However, while my code finds the file dimension correctly, it does not store the file properly.

For reference, the "ascii_image.txt" I am using right now looks like this:

```
  Z
 ZZZ
ZZZZZ
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned int i32;                     // integers with 32 bits

void printTable(int rows, int columns, char table[rows][columns])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
        printf("%c", table[i][j]);

      printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\n");
}


int getAsciiImageDimension(i32* image_height, i32* image_width, const char* file_name)
{
  FILE *image = fopen(file_name, "r");

  int number_of_rows = 0;
  int row_length = 0;
  int max_row_length = 0;
  char character = (char) fgetc(image);

  while (character != EOF)
    {
      if (character == '\n')
        {
          number_of_rows = number_of_rows + 1;

          if (max_row_length < row_length)
            max_row_length = row_length;

          row_length = 0;
        }
      else
        row_length = row_length + 1;

      character = (char) fgetc(image);
    }

  *image_height = number_of_rows;
  *image_width = max_row_length;
  return 0;
}

void readAsciiImage(i32 image_height, i32 image_width, char array[image_height][image_width], const char* file_name)
{
  FILE *image = fopen(file_name, "r");
  i32 i = 0;
  i32 j = 0;

  char character = (char) fgetc(image);

  while (character != EOF)
    {
      array[i][j] = character;

      if (character == '\n')
        {
          while (j < image_width)
            {
              array[i][j] = ' ';
              j = j + 1;
            }

          i = i + 1;
        }
      else
        j = j + 1;

      character = (char) fgetc(image);
    }
}


int main()
{
  int image_width;
  int image_height;
  getAsciiImageDimension(&image_height, &image_width, "ascii_image.txt");
  printf("image_height = %d and image_width = %d \n", image_height, image_width);
  char array[image_height][image_width];
  readAsciiImage(image_height, image_width, array, "ascii_image.txt");
  printTable(image_height, image_width, array);    // the array seems to be wrong

  return 0;
}
```

Edit 1: Below you can see a picture of the output I get compared to the output I expect. I do not understand why the second line of my output is emtpy.

[image]

Edit 2: For any future reader: The following code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void printTable(int rows, int columns, char table[rows][columns])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
        printf("%c", table[i][j]);

      printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\n");
}


int getAsciiImageDimension(unsigned int* image_height, unsigned int* image_width, const char* file_name)
{
  FILE *image = fopen(file_name, "r");

  // Here we check whether opening the given file was successful.
  if (!image)
    {
      printf("Invalid File\n");
      return -1;
    }

  int number_of_rows = 0;
  int row_length = 0;
  int max_row_length = 0;
  char character = (char) fgetc(image);

  while (character != EOF)
    {
      if (character == '\n')
        {
          number_of_rows = number_of_rows + 1;

          if (max_row_length < row_length)
            max_row_length = row_length;

          row_length = 0;
        }
      else
        row_length = row_length + 1;

      character = (char) fgetc(image);
    }
  fclose(image);
  *image_height = number_of_rows;
  *image_width = max_row_length;
  return 0;
}

void readAsciiImage(unsigned int image_height, unsigned int image_width, char array[image_height][image_width], const char* file_name)
{
  FILE *image = fopen(file_name, "r");
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int j = 0;

  char character = (char) fgetc(image);

  while (character != EOF)
    {
      array[i][j] = character;

      if (character == '\n')
        {
          while (j < image_width)
            {
              array[i][j] = ' ';
              j = j + 1;
            }

          i = i + 1;
          j = 0;
        }
      else
        j = j + 1;

      character = (char) fgetc(image);
    }
  fclose(image);
}


int main()
{
  unsigned int image_width;
  unsigned int image_height;
  getAsciiImageDimension(&image_height, &image_width, "ascii_image.txt");
  printf("image_height = %d and image_width = %d \n", image_height, image_width);
  char array[image_height][image_width];
  readAsciiImage(image_height, image_width, array, "ascii_image.txt");
  printTable(image_height, image_width, array);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *first* line that does not do what you expected?

Comment: Why return an error code from `getAsciiImageDimension()` if you didn't intend to check for it?

Comment: How did you assume that `unsigned int` is 32 bits?

Comment: `fgetc()` returns an `int`. Knowing that, why do you deliberately cast its return to a `char` before storing it into a `char`?

Comment: @ScottHunter: I made an edit.

Comment: Your edit did not answer my question (which was asking which line *of code*).

Comment: Why ignore the return of `fopen()` in `readAsciiImage()`? The subsequent call to `fgetc()` would invoke undefined behaviour if `fopen()` had returned `NULL`.

Comment: @Haris: I ignore the reutrn value for fopen here for since I am still in the testing phase.

Comment: @ScottHunter: The line   "printTable(image_height, image_width, array);" , which should be line 97, does yield an unexpected print. The problem should be somewhere in the "readAsciiImage" function.

Comment: What is stopping you from finding out which line in `readAsciiImage` it is?

Comment: One would think that checking the return value of a library function is exactly what you should be doing in the *testing phase*.

Comment: In `readAsciiImage` you need to reset `j = 0` after a newline.

Comment: @Haris If you wait for the testing phase of a complete program to start checking return values, you are likely to wind up with a big mess of code that doesn't work like you hoped it would. Similar to the code posted here...

Comment: And `typedef unsigned int i32;`? No one's explicitly said this yet: don't create your own non-portable types.  There's no guarantee that an `int` is 32 bits.  If you want a 32-bit value, use `int32_t` from `stdint.h` - and even that's not guaranteed to exist.  It will only exist if the platform is twos-complement and has a type with no padding that exactly matches that size.  Full portability requires use of `int_least32_t`.

Comment: Find the man who told you to use `(char) fgetc` and give him a thorough beating.